# What is the use of this combination of operators in python, " \ <return> | "?

Tags: python

Well, I ran over a piece of code and I could not quite figure out its function. 
It goes like this:

```py
thresholds = (image[:,:,0] < rgbThreshold[0]) \
            | (image[:,:,1] < rgbThreshold[1]) \
            | (image[:,:,2] < rgbThreshold[2])
```

It's that bit over there,

> \ <"return"> | (image[:,:,1] < ....

I can't quite figure out what it does.

If anyone is wondering what this code is meant to be doing, there are a set of RGB thresholds (redThreshold, green....) and an image "image".

I just select all the pixels that are below the specified threshold. Then I access them by `colorSelect[threshold] = [0,0,0]` i.e. blacken them (colorSelect is a numpy array that represents an image by its RBG pixel values.)

Comment: What is the type of `image` ?

Comment: You can't figure out what `'\'` does, or why there is a new-line, or what `|` does, or what is `image[:,:,1]`, or what `<` does? be more specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` means `or` and `\` is just used to make the content of line in next line to make it according to PEP-8 guidelines and user able to read code better this way.

Here:

```
thresholds = (image[:,:,0] < rgbThreshold[0]) \
            | (image[:,:,1] < rgbThreshold[1]) \
            | (image[:,:,2] < rgbThreshold[2])
```

is  same as:

```
thresholds = (image[:,:,0] < rgbThreshold[0]) | (image[:,:,1] < rgbThreshold[1]) | (image[:,:,2] < rgbThreshold[2])
```

Comment: But hey, what does doing an "or" this way achieve?

Comment: @steve Each expression of the form `image[:,:,x] < rgbThreshold[x]` returns a boolean, which is `True` or `False`. Then doing `|` between those three boolean values means that `thresholds` will be `True` if (and only if) at least one of the `image` elements is less than its RGB threshold

Comment: @steve it's boolean expession and using `or` operation, done to make Thresolds true if in image ay of the regbthresold criteria is meet

Answer (score 1):

The `\` is breaking it into a new line for easier reading and the pipe character is used as a [bitwise or](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) to combine the three values.

Answer (score 1):

`image[:,:,1]` means `image[0:():(1)]` which means `image.__getitem__(0, (), (1))`
`,` is an empty tuple in this context